# What is the sigma representation of adding two or more vectors with an identical number of dimensions into one vector?

Tags: notation

What is the sigma representation of adding two or more vectors with an identical number of dimensions into one vector?

For example, something like this:
$$
[x_1,y_1,z_1,\dots,n_1]+[x_2,y_2,z_2,\dots,n_2]+[x_3,y_3,z_3,\dots,n_3]+\dots+ [x_m,y_m,z_m...n_m] \\= \begin{bmatrix}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \bigg),\bigg( \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_i \bigg),\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m} z_i\bigg)..,\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m} n_i\bigg)\end{bmatrix}
$$

But i am sure there's a shorter formal way of doing it

Comment: You can just type your LaTeX into the question box and it will render with MathJax.  No need to paste an image from codecogs.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It doesn't look the same

Comment: I've gone ahead and done it.  You just need to enclose the displayed math between double-dollar signs.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Awsome, it looks exactly the same with MathJax, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 \sum_i^m [x_i , y_i, \ldots , n_i]
$$
will do the job, assuming your reader knows how to add vectors.

If you're doing this a lot you might want to name the vectors $v_i$.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seemed unclear to me not to include anything that would indicate an addition of the dimensions $$(x_1 +x_2+x_3...)$$ , is this a formal representation ?

Comment: You're not adding dimensions. All the vectors have the same dimension, as you know. You aren't (and can't) name the dimension, because you're using $x, y, \ldots , n$ to name the coordinates, rather than going for double subscripts. (Euler would approve - makes for readability.) If you go for double subscripts then it's clear that you are just adding the rows (or columns) of a matrix.

Comment: Yes, i meant the addition of the identical dimensions, so what you are suggesting would look like this ? :  $$\sum_{i=1}^{m} [[v_i]_1,[v_i]_2,[v_i]_3..,[v_i]_n]$$

Comment: Yes, probably without the inner brackets. Perhaps $v_{i,j}$. But your $x,y$ etc is OK.

Comment: But wouldn't this still force me to elaborate with the addition of :  $$=[x_1,y_1,z_1,\dots,n_1]+[x_2,y_2,z_2,\dots,n_2]+[x_3,y_3,z_3,\dots,n_3]+\dots+ [x_m,y_m,z_m...n_m]$$

Comment: I don't think so. Apparently you don't either since you've accepted the answer. I wouldn't use $n$ for the last coordinate. Perhaps $x, y, \ldots, z$ or $a,b, \ldots, z$ (as might Euler).